# creating and resolving promises in protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I am writing a test case for adding store information in the page for Angular app using Protractor, where initially I am counting the number of stores I already have and after the test block is done I expect the count to increase by one so for that I am doing this by following this link of creating promises [How to create and manipulate promises in Protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055400/how-to-create-and-manipulate-promises-in-protractor)

```
describe('myApp', function() {
  var items,startCount;

  var testPromise = function(){
    items = element.all(by.repeater('store in storelist'));
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
    items.count().then(function(orgCount){
       startCount = orgCount;
       console.log('Start Count: '+ startCount); //prints correct value e.g, 6
    }, function(error){
       console.log(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  };

it('should accept valid data for adding new store', function() {
   var cNum = null;
   testPromise().then(function(result){
      cNum = result;
      console.log('cNUm value: '+ cNum); //this value doesn't get printed in console
   });
   /* Code for adding test fields in store page */

   expect(items.count()).toBe(cNum+1);
 });
});
```

I expect the store count to be same at the end of the test. count() is resolving a promise and correct value of store count gets printed in testPromise() but in it block when I call testPromise().then method it never goes in that 'then' block

and the end result says

```
Message:
 Expected 6 to be 1.
 Stacktrace:
  Error: Failed expectation
```

I also researched a bit more in webdriver.promise.Promise() from this link http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_promise_Promise.html and tried using that for creating a promise and resolving its value but not sure what the problem is. Either I get error message saying 'expected 6 to be NaN' or 'expected 6 to be 1' Am I not resolving a promise or writing 'then' block correctly? Would appreciate some insights/help on this issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a working example of a user-defined function for use in Protractor which creates and fulfills (or rejects) a promise:

```
// Get the text of an element and convert to an integer.
// Returns a promise.
function getTextAsInteger(element, radix) {
  // Specify a default radix for the call to parseInt.
  radix = radix || 10;
  // Create a promise to be fulfilled or rejected later.
  var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
  // Get the text from the element. The call to getText
  // returns a promise.
  element.getText().then(
    function success(text) {
      var num = parseInt(text, radix);
      if (!isNaN(num)) {
        // Successfully converted text to integer.
        deferred.fulfill(num);
      } else {
        // Error converting text to integer.
        deferred.reject('could not parse "$1" into an integer'
          .replace('$1', text));
      }
    },
    function error(reason) {
      // Reject our promise and pass the reason from the getText rejection.
      deferred.reject(reason);
    });

  // Return the promise. This will be resolved or rejected
  // when the above call to getText is resolved.
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

The function takes `element` as an argument and calls its `getText()` method which itself returns a promise. On a successful call to `getText()`, parse the text as an integer and fulfill the promise. If `getText()` rejects, we pass the reason to our own reject call.

To use this function, pass in an element promise:

```
var numField = element(by.id('num-field'));
getTextAsInteger(numField).then(
    function success(num) {
        console.log(num);
    }, 
    function error(reason) {
        console.error(reason);
    });
```

or:

```
var numField = element(by.id('num-field'));
expect(getTextAsInteger(numField)).toEqual(jasmine.any(Number));
expect(getTextAsInteger(numField)).toBeGreaterThan(0);
```

Answer (score 48):

### Creation

For creating a promise in protractor, you have to write:

```
var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
var promise = deferred.promise;
```

---

### Callbacks

The callbacks are invoked asynchronously.
You can register one (or more) "on success" callbacks:

```
promise.then(function() {
   ...
});
```

you can also register one (or more) "on error" callback:

```
promise.then(null, function() {
   ...
});
```

These registrations could be chained:

```
promise.then(function() {
   ...
}).then(function() {
   ...
}).then(null, function() {
   ...
}).then(function() {

}, function() {
   ...
}).then(onSuccess, onFailure);
```

---

### Resolution

#### Success

The "on success" callbacks are invoked when the promise is resolved successfully:

```
deferred.fulfill(value);
```

#### Failure

The "on failure" callbacks are invoked when the promise is resolved successfully:

```
deferred.reject(new Error('a problem occurs'));
```

---

### In your code

you missed the resolution step. You have to fulfill the promise.

A more complete reference is available in the [Webdriver.js documentation](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.html)

Comment: Could someone please show a more concrete example using this? I have tried to follow this answer but I am still failing to get this working.

Comment: @BlakeBiker i think you should ask your own question describing your specific problem

Comment: The link above to the webdriver documentation appears to be out of date.

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden fix link

Comment: what do I need to import from the protractor package in order to use protractor.promise.defer?  My IDE is complaining "cannot find name 'protractor'" at that line.

Answer (score -2):

I got the same issue and solved it by creating a promise for the expected item count:

```
it('should accept valid data for adding new store', function() {
    // Given
    let expectedCountAfterNewRow = items.count().then((cnt)=>{return cnt+1}); 
    // Note: items.count() is a promise so the expected count should a promise too

    // When
    /* Code for adding test fields in store page */

    // Then
   expect(items.count()).toEqual(expectedCountAfterNewRow);
});
```