# AngluarJS Protractor tests: function should return a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, protractor

I got a function which enter some values into a form. This should return a promise, so my test waits till the function is finished and the values are entered in the form. How do I do this in a protractor test?

```
function enterSomeValuesIntoForm() {
    // do some stuff
    element(by.id('value1')).sendKeys('hello');
    element(by.id('value2')).sendKeys('is it me you looking for?');
    element(by.id('submitButton')).click();
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating and resolving promises in protractor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289431/creating-and-resolving-promises-in-protractor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you don't actually need to return a promise from this function. All of the actions performed during the function call would be controlled and queued by the [Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md):

> WebDriverJS (and thus, Protractor) APIs are entirely asynchronous. All
>   functions return promises.
>
> WebDriverJS maintains a queue of pending promises, called the control
>   flow, to keep execution organized.

You can still though return the promise returned by `click()`:

```
function enterSomeValuesIntoForm() {
    // do some stuff
    element(by.id('value1')).sendKeys('hello');
    element(by.id('value2')).sendKeys('is it me you looking for?');
    return element(by.id('submitButton')).click();
});
```

so that you can later explicitly resolve:

```
enterSomeValuesIntoForm().then(function () {
    // form is submitted at this point
});
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!