# In Protractor, how to check aria-hidden = "true" or "false"

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I need to check **aria-hidden="true" or "false"** depending on the click

```
 <tr ng-class="{'submitted' : (position.submitted) }" ng-repeat- 
 start="position in demandFactory.openings | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
                    <td><span ng-click="openDemand(position.demandID)"><span ng-show="position.demandID == demandFactory.selectedDemand">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down glyphicon-small" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span ng-show="position.demandID != demandFactory.selectedDemand">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right glyphicon-small" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </span></span>
                        <span class="jobName">&nbsp{{ position.name }} </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ position.demandID }}</td>
                    <td>{{ position.rotation }}</td>
                    <td>{{ position.headcount }}</td>
                    <td>{{ position.num }}</td>
                    <td>{{ position.approved }}</td>
                </tr>
```

In the test case I have accessed the element but could get the check **aria-hidden** value.

```
  var aPromiseOfRows = element.all(by.repeater('position in demandFactory.openings').row(0).column("position.name"));
  aPromiseOfRows.getText().then(function(text) {
  console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get element attribute value in Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961197/get-element-attribute-value-in-protractor)

Comment: As flagged by @JeffC, give the existing question and answers a read through. Most likely you will get the solution you are looking for there too.

Answer (score 0):

With Protractor, you can use `getAttribute` thats documented [here](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute). `getText()` returns the text inside the element and not the element attribute(s).

You can do something like this

- Get the element you want to test using `get(index` thats documented [here](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get).
- Get attribute inside `expect()`
- Use a matcher like toBe/toEqual appropriately for your use case

Pseudo code:

```
var aPromiseOfRow = element.all(by.repeater('position in demandFactory.openings').get(0);
expect(aPromiseOfRow.getAttribute('aria-hidden')).toEqual('true');
```

If you are looking to access the value for later use then use something like this

```
var val;
aPromiseOfRow.getAttribute('aria-hidden').then(function(attrValue) {
   val = attrValue;
});
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: there are two spans in the same td. I need to check aria hidden of both the spans. They are nested spans

Comment: Suggest add appropriate CSS class/id selector for the `<span>` elements. Then use `aPromiseOfRow.element(by.css("span-selector-here")).getAttribute("aria-hidden")`. The logic is pretty simple. Basically get the element then call `getAttribute("aria-hidden")`.

Comment: Failed: aPromiseOfRows.element is not a function i got an error

Comment: Thats because `aPromiseOfRows` is an Element array. What you need is `aPromiseOfRows.get(0)` to get the first element in that array. You can then use the `.element(by.css('span-selector'))` to get to the span element. Notice the response above its `aPromiseOfRow` not `aPromiseOfRows`. On a lighter note, suggest spare a thought on the code you are using. Without understanding what you are writing, there is little value in coding session over SO :)

Comment: Below is what i did. and i got No element found using locator: By(css selector, .glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down glyphicon-small)
  var aPromiseOfRows = element.all(by.repeater('position in demandFactory.openings').row(0));

  var aPromiseOfRow = aPromiseOfRows.get(0);

  console.log(aPromiseOfRow.element(by.css('.glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down glyphicon-small')).getAttribute("aria-hidden"));

Comment: `by.css('.glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down glyphicon-small')` that wont work. Let me point you in the right direction. For any automation work, one needs to understand how selectors (CSS or XPATH) work. Refer https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp for the basics of CSS selectors. In specific to your problem, search for "name1 name2" on that page. You will get your answer as to what to use.