# Protractor: browser.getCurrentUrl().then ( ( url ) => { return url; } ); always returning undefined

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am trying to get current url and want to store it as string but .then is always return undefined. Following is the function code:

```
navigateToLandingPage() {
          let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
          let currentURL: string;
          browser.getCurrentUrl().then ( (url) => {
            currentURL = url;
          } );
          if (currentURL !== 'operator') {
           browser.get('localhost:3000/#/operator');
           browser.wait(EC.urlContains('/operator'), 10000);
      }
```

I am calling it form spec in this way:

```
describe('Checking Module', () => {
  let page: CalendarModule;
  let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new CalendarModule();
  });
  it('Clicking on Calendar should redirect to Calendar Module', () => {
      page.commonMethodObj.navigateToLandingPage();
      let calendarLink = page.getCalendarLink();
       calendarLink.click().then(() => {
       browser.wait(EC.urlContains('/calendar'), 50000);
       expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('/calendar');
      });
  });
});
```

I am using following versions of dependencies:

```
"@angular/core": "2.3.1",
"jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
"protractor": "~4.0.13"
```

Comment: `calendarLink.click()` method is thenable; however, it is not needed since Protractor makes these asynchronous calls appear syncrhonous with jasminewd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire behavior and the flow of the code execution is *asynchronous* and orchestrated by the [WebDriver Control Flow](http://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow). In other words, you cannot expect that `currentURL` variable would actually get the current URL value on this line:

```
if (currentURL !== 'operator') {
```

Instead, *work inside the callback*:

```
browser.getCurrentUrl().then ( (currentURL) => {  
    if (currentURL !== 'operator') {
        browser.get('localhost:3000/#/operator');
        browser.wait(EC.urlContains('/operator'), 10000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah correct!! But what if i want  to return something from promise and use it later. How could it be achieved then??

Comment: @ArjunSingh awesome, you can use the deferred object ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24290262/771848)).