# How to catch ngToast messages in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am new to angular and protractor.We use protractor for functional testing and integrated with jenkins.

**Problem**

In some screens we use `ng-toast` to show toaster messages(mainly for server response messages like 'save filed' etc.).But protractor could not catch these, since it will wait for all angular timeouts(including toaster timeout) to complete.Showing error:

```
Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds.
```

I tried  to set `ignoreSynchronization` too.

How to tackle this. I am really stuck on this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long search on google I got answer.We can make use of promises with `browser.wait`in test cases those needs to wait for toaster messages.

```
        .....  
        browser.wait(function() {
                var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();

                  getToaster().then(function(){
                      deferred.fulfill(true);
                      expect(getToaster().isDisplayed()).toBe(true);//and other assertions
                  });
                  return deferred.promise;
                });
       .....
```

This is well described in this [blog](http://docsplendid.com/tags/wait-for-element)
Also more details about `protractor.promise` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055400/how-to-create-and-manipulate-promises-in-protractor/21055627#21055627)

Alternatively I did it in another way as:

```
 ...
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000);//set timeout for element 
     expect(toaster.getToaster().isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
     browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1);//reset
   ....
```

But in a protractor way of doing is `browser.wait` with `ExpectedCondition` which is described in the [protractor api](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions) including custom conditions.I am currently using this explicit wait approach.

Comment: What is getToaster() doing? I've been experimenting with this, but can't get it to work.