# how to resolve promise value as a normal value

Tags: promise, protractor, es6-promise, rsvp-promise

How can we resolve promise to a normal number value .

I have use case in protractor automation in the first i have to call a asynchronous operation then that result value which should not be a promise .

I am using protractor framework

**EDIT**

```
var mobileNumber = database.generateMobileNumber().then(function(mobileNumber){
    done();
    return mobileNumber;
}); 
var number=Promise.resolve(mobileNumber);
```

Comment: Can you show us your source code?

Comment: var mobileNumber = database.generateMobileNumber().then(function(mobileNumber) {
            done();
            return mobileNumber;
        });
        var number=Promise.resolve(mobileNumber);

Comment: I'm using this in jasmine spec

Comment: database.generateMobileNumber() is an asynchronous call

Comment: am using protractor framework in which jasmine to test the app

Comment: are you clear with my answers, any info is needed

Comment: and one more thing to add is I want to add that resolved variable in global scope so that other operations can be done using that value

Comment: @Genzotto. Did you get my question clearly. Do i need to give more info ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why you might want to work with non-promise values, but i think you should play with browser.wait()
I didn't checked this, test this code to see if it will work.
This approach is bad, think twice before use it:

```
function getMobileNumber() {
var result;
var promise = database.generateMobileNumber().then(mobileNumber=> {
    result = mobileNumber;
    return true;
});

browser.wait(promise, 10000)
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ? You can find in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055400/how-to-create-and-manipulate-promises-in-protractor) more information about managing promises with protractor.

```
var mobileNumber = database.generateMobileNumber().then(function(mobileNumber){
    done();
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
    return deferred.fulfill(mobileNumber);
});
```

**EDIT**

```
var mobileNumber = database.generateMobileNumber().then(function(value){
    done();
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
    return deferred.fulfill(value);
});
```

the previous one is not clean as the same name (mobileNumber) is used in two different contexts. I don't know the result of this.

Comment: when i try to run it says as  Failed: deferred.resolve is not a function

Comment: can i know the usage of deferred object in protractor

Comment: I can not find any documents or info in webdriver or protractor website about deferred object info and usage

Comment: var mobileNumber = database.generateMobileNumber().then(function(mobileNumber){
    done();
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
    return deferred.fulfill(mobileNumber);
});
console.log(mobileNumber);

Comment: can i know when to use defer object @stephane

Comment: OK, please update your comment instead of creating new ones. And please let me some time to answer you. I am not spending all my time on stackoverflow and I want you to respect that.

Comment: The defer() function applies to a promise and tells to protractor that you will manually resolve the promise yourself. With that function, you can create your own promises and resolve it when you want, with the value you want. This might be exactly what you want, because you can resolve a promise with a simple number that way. Now be careful that when you write `myfunction().then(function(myvalue))`, the value of 'myvalue' is the resolved promise returned by `myfunction()`. It is dangerous then to write then(function(mobileNumber)) cause it could lead to unwanted behaviour.