# Resolve promise in an external (Helper) file

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am using the JavaScript testing framework, Protractor.

I have an external utility class file that I am using to organize common logic within my test specs. See [Using Page Objects to Organize Tests](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md).

There seems to be an issue when I take a block of code that resolves a promise, and put in into my Helper utility class file, for the same use.

Example:

---

In an individual spec file, this code works as expected:

test.spec.js:

```
it('should display the Protractor workflow text', function() {
    // match variable
    var match = false;

    // get elements by tag
    var scanElements = element.all(by.css('div')).each(function(el) {
        el.getText().then(function(text) {
            var sp = text.split(' '); // split by <space>
            for (var i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
                if (sp[i] == 'Protractor') {
                    match = true;
                }
            }
        });
    });

    // on complete
    scanElements.then(function() {
        console.log(match); // returns true
    });
});
```

However, if I separate this logic into my Helper utility class, the return value is `undefined`.

Helper.js

```
/** containsText [process]
 *  searchs for text in tag elements (i.e. 'string' in <a>, 'string' in <div>)

 *  @param string - tag name to limit
 *  @param string - string value to search against
 *
 *  @return boolean - if string is found
*/
this.containsText = function (tagName, stringValue) {
    // match variable
    var match = false;

    // get elements by tag
    var scanElements = element.all(by.css(tagName)).each(function(el) {
        el.getText().then(function(text) {
            var sp = text.split(' '); // split by <space>
            for (var i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
                if (sp[i] == stringValue) {
                    match = true;
                }
            }
        });
    });

    // on complete
    scanElements.then(function() {
        return match;
    });
}
```

test.spec.js

```
it('should display the Protractor workflow text', function() {
    console.log(helper.containsText('div', 'Protractor'));  // does not wait to resolve, returns undefined
});
```

---

Edit: All of the links to similar questions on Stack Overflow have to deal with asynchronous calls via Ajax requests. I'm looking for a solution for the Protractor / Webdriver framework. I have read documentation on creating promises with Protractor, and have tried the following as well:

Helper.js

```
this.containsText = function (tagName, stringValue) {
    // get elements by tag
    var scanElements = element.all(by.css(tagName)).each(function(el) {
        el.getText().then(function(text) {
            var sp = text.split(' '); // split by <space>
            for (var i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
                if (sp[i] == stringValue) {
                    return true;  // fufill outer promise and break execution
                }
            }
        });
    });

    return scanElements;
}
```

test.spec.js

```
helper.containsText('div', 'Protractor').then(function(f) {
    console.log(f);
});
```

Still looking for some assistance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: There's a big difference between `console.log(match);` and `return match;`. You've not just "separate(d) this logic into my Helper utility class" you've also totally changed the flow of the script.

Comment: Protractor code here [How to create and manipulate promises in Protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055400/how-to-create-and-manipulate-promises-in-protractor)